# Finding out the day

Tags: php, mysql

I want to find out the day of the week based on a databese date entry.

for example: suppose i fetch a value from the database like `03-03-1988`, i want to print the day it was like monday or tuesday. how can i calculate that?

thanxx in advance..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can do in the [mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek)

like

`SELECT DAYOFWEEK(date) as weekday from mytable`

> Returns the weekday index for date (1
>   = Sunday, 2 = Monday, …, 7 = Saturday).

Comment: Doing it with your date, 1988-03-03, returns 5 which would be Thursday. MySQL also has WEEKDAY(date) function, which inexplicably gives a different index, 3, but the same day is indicated.

Answer (score 2):

```
$tm = strtotime('03-03-1988');
print strftime('%A', $tm);
```

Be careful about `strtotime`, though. When feeding it "XX-XX-XXXX" it's being parsed as "DD-MM-YYYY", not "MM-DD-YYYY" as one might expect.

Answer (score 2):

```
$myDay = date("l", mktime(0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 1988));
```

The result is the day you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You need strtotime and date functions.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$d="03-03-1988";
$i= strtotime($d);   

echo date("l",$i);
?>
```